# Optional viewmodel attribute for IFormFile

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel

For my ASP.NET MVC project i have a viewmodel as follows:

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public IFormFile ProfileImage { get; set; }
}
```

In my `CreateProfile.cshtml` i want to force users to upload a profile image. so by adding `[Required]` attribute i add validation in the form. But when users are Editing their profile, the IFormFile should not be `[Required]`.

This is ofcourse possible by using two diffrent viewmodels `CreateProfileViewModel` and `EditPRofileViewModel`. 
My question is basically:

- Is it possible to temporary 'unset' the `[Required]` attribute or make it optional in a viewmodel.
- Also, Is it possible to trick the viewmodel that the IFormFile is set by assigning a placeholder image (but also preventing razor from submitting the placeholder)
- In my current (working) solution i have 2 seperate viewmodels for `Create` and `Edit`, but is there a nicer, cleaner and better way to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: View models are classes that are specifically tailored to the needs of a given view. So I would suggest to keep it as separate view models.